# Adding global error handling to WCF REST service

Tags: wcf, rest

I have a WCF/REST Web Service that I'm trying to add a global exception handler to. I'm looking for something similar to the Application_Error event in a standard .NET website.

I've found lots of info about using IErrorHandler and IServiceBehavior like what's detailed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx#Y1479

That seems like what I need, but every example I've found assumes that the service is defined in the web.config. I'm not doing that - I'm using RouteTables, configured in the global.asax, like so:

```
 public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterRoutes();
    }

    private void RegisterRoutes()
    {
        // Edit the base address of Service1 by replacing the "Service1" string below

        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("", new WebServiceHost2Factory(), typeof(myService)));


    }
```

So, given that, how do I configure my custom IErrorHandler and IServiceBehavior? Am I even on the right track, given that I'm using a RouteTable rather than configuring it via the web.config? I'm very new to WCF....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The wiring up of your `IServiceBehaviour` can be achieved by creating a custom `WebServiceHostFactory` that overrides `CreateServiceHost`.

For example if you have a class `GlobalErrorHandlerBehaviour` which implements `IServiceBehavior`, then you could wire it up as follows:

```
public class CustomWebServiceHostFactory : WebServiceHostFactory
{
    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(System.Type serviceType, System.Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        return ApplyGlobalErrorHandler(base.CreateServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses));
    }

    private ServiceHost ApplyGlobalErrorHandler(ServiceHost serviceHost)
    {
        serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(new GlobalErrorHandlerBehaviour());
        return serviceHost;
    }
}
```

You would then update your call to the `ServiceRoute` constructor to pass in this custom factory.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Please give this guy all the points!  :)