# DEV environment Kendo AJAX Jquery call works -- UAT environment gives 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

This code works perfectly in DEV environment. Now that it's in UAT, it's returning a 405 Method Not Allowed error. All I'm trying to do is a GET. For some reason, the response headers in the console are now showing "Allow: POST". I don't know why it's allowing POST, and I don't know how to change it. Here's the code below. The call failing is the first one being made to the GetThings stored procedure. Why is the response header allowing a POST when I'm trying to do a GET? How can I change the response header from POST to GET? Again, this works perfectly in DEV. Thanks

````
    var comboBox = $("#cappfMTF").kendoComboBox({
        dataTextField: "Name",
        dataValueField: "ID",
        template: '#:data.ID# - #:data.Name#',
        placeholder: "Select Thing",
        height: 260,
        autoBind: true,
        dataSource: {
            type: "json",
            serverFiltering: true,
            serverPaging: true,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/_layouts/15/_Service/Service.svc/GetThings",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                        XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
                    }
                }
            },
            change: function () {
                var mtfValue = comboBox.value();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/_layouts/15/_Service/_Services.svc/v_Things?$filter=IDName eq '" + mtfValue + "'",
                    dataType: "json",
                    beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                        XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
                    },
                    success: function (result) {
                        //set value of diff dropdown 
                        var diffCombo = $("#cappfMarket").data("kendoComboBox");
                        if (result.d.length == 1) {
                            var diffValue = result.d[0].diff;
                            diffCombo.value(diffValue);
                        }
                    }
                });
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    Id: "ID",
                    fields: {
                        ID: { type: "string" },
                        Name: { type: "string" }
                    }
                },
                data: function (response) {                  
                    return response.d;
                }
            }
        }
    }).data('kendoComboBox');```
````

Comment: you might want to use fiddler or postman , see if you can call the enpoint on your UTA with them that will help you work out if the en point is working and if its a server setup issue or a code one, i suspect there is a difference in how UTA is setup from dev,

Comment: But other GET calls I'm making are working fine in UAT. For some reason the Response Headers say "Allow: POST" in UAT, but it says "Allow: GET" in DEV. Driving me crazy. Is there any way to manually override the "Allow: POST"?

Comment: The difference is going to be in the server environment. In dev I imagine you are working with localhost where UAT will be a remote server instance with potentially different configuration. What is your backend web server? IIS or something else? Can we see the definition of the server method you are posting to and the nature of the response it returns? You say other GET calls are working. Do those server methods differ from the one that is failing in the way they are defined and the way in which they build the response?

Comment: I agree shoulds like an ISS or web config issue maybe check out https://inthetechpit.com/2019/02/24/enable-put-and-delete-http-verbs-for-webapi-with-cors-on-iis-8-5/ it shows how to add verbs to your web config

Comment: @NigelK I'm using WCF. The only way the other GET calls differ is that this particular GET call is using a SQL stored procedure instead of a view.

Comment: @PatrickHume thanks, I came across this as well but it's for WebAPI and I'm using WCF

Comment: @nigelK receiving this in the logs:

`System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportReplyChannelAcceptor+TransportReplyChannel, cannot be used for communication because it has been Aborted.`

Comment: have you tried adding the verbs in WCF `` [WebGet] "  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/wcf-web-http-programming-model-overview as for the other error check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15152954/wcf-system-servicemodel-channels-servicechannel-has-been-aborted